# Kendo TreeList lost row color

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

Kendo treelist in angular js lost row color after expand and collapse operation. 
Please  check attached link for more details.

http://dojo.telerik.com/enEqE

Comment: What is the criteria to change the row color ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown criteria is simple flag on basis I need to change the row. Currently even changing the color without any condition, color also lost after row expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from telerik itself. Its required to add the code on expand event and also required to wrap it inside the settimeout function.

Here is the updated dojo.
http://dojo.telerik.com/UTocid